# How can I center an equation inside an align environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

This is basically the setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c\\
a &= b + c\\
\center{a = b + c \quad a = b + c}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the last line in the `align` environment centered independently of the lines above.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A single equation in `align` is centered, so with `gather`
you get both equations centered; otherwise, nest `align` inside `gather`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

A single equation in \texttt{align} is centered, so with \texttt{gather}
you get both equations centered:
\begin{gather}
a = b + c
a = b + c \quad a = b + c
\end{gather}
If you have \emph{two} equations to align with each other and
one to be centered, nest \texttt{align} in \texttt{gather}
\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c\\
x &= b + c + d + e
\end{align}\\
a = b + c \quad a = b + c \quad a = b + c
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was experimenting a similar solution, but with `aligned` inside `gather`, with two alignment groups. Strangely it didn't result in the normal spacing between the groups, while `alignedat{2}` works fine, or your `align` solution. Can you explain it?

Comment: @Bernard The problem with `aligned` is that it doesn't number each row.

Comment: But it might be wanted so in some situations: just one number for the rows in aligned, coming from `gather`.

Comment: Thanks, nesting `align` in gather solved it! How could I have figured this out myself?

Comment: @LenarHoyt Page 29 in the manual of `amsmath`: “The structures `align`, `alignat`, etc., are designed for top-level use and for the most part cannot be nested inside some other displayed equation structure. The chief exception is that `align` and most of its variants can be used inside the `gather` environment.” I acknowledge it's not really so prominent. ;-)

Comment: The most elegant, bug, seamlessly flawless method! to solve \centering that is an overflow, and relative to lipsum[1] etc...

Answer (score 16):

I suspect you actually want to use a `gather` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
a = b + c\\
d = e + f \qquad g = h + i
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But there are more equations above which are aligned (fixed this in my question).

Comment: @LenarHoyt - I'm afraid it's quite unclear to me what your actual formatting objectives may be. By the way, are you really trying to typeset trivial equations of the form `a = b + c`? If not, please post the actual equations you're looking to typeset. Please also be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @LenarHoyt - Is there something stopping you from taking my code and inserting an additional row in the `gather` environment?

Comment: @Mico Perhaps, the issues is that if there are various other equations are in the document, then how does the numbering of each line can be distinguished, limited to each of those respective equations.

Comment: @bonCodigo - I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand what you're driving at. Please clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Your MWE is not clear about the variables you want to align with each other. Please, make the variables unique and say which ones you want to align with each other, so you can get a helpful answer.

For centering, I think `align` always centers the equations, but if you wish to control the spacing, you may consider `alignat`.

If you you don't care about aligning the second equation, then you need to go with `gather` not `align`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    a &= b + c \quad &\\
    x &= y + z & a &= b + c
\end{alignat}

\begin{gather} 
    a = b + c\\
    a = b + c \quad a = b + c
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my question. I've updated it.

Comment: @LenarHoyt does this help?