# Centering/Indenting Equation In Align Environment so That It Is Indented Below Text

Tags: equations, align

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\begin{document}
\raggedright
{\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

We first convert the second-order nonhomogeneous Cauchy-Euler differential equation into standard form:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{ d^2y }{ dx^2 } + \dfrac{2}{x} \dfrac{ dy }{ dx } - \dfrac{4y}{x^2} = 4x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I want the equation

```
\dfrac{ d^2y }{ dx^2 } + \dfrac{2}{x} \dfrac{ dy }{ dx } - \dfrac{4y}{x^2} = 4x
```

to have some indentation so it is centred below the text above it.

I tried `{gather}` as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326009/how-can-i-center-an-equation-inside-an-align-environment?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but it doesn't seem to change anything? I also looked through numerous other questions on alignment, but none seemed to provide a fix to my situation. Alignment questions have been asked many times in the past, so If there's an answer that already has a fix for my problem, then I would appreciate a link to it.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: You are using the `fleqn` option, which does not center equations but rather sets them at a fixed margin (which you are putting to zero).

Comment: @campa Is there any way to override it for a moment?

Comment: What makes this particular equation different from all the others? If you set `fleqn`, then all equation will be left aligned and I see no reason for setting just one equation centered.

Comment: @egreg I want it to fall below the text above it, but in an indented fashion. Perhaps not centring, but some sort of indentation that makes it clear that the equation is within the context of the text above it.

Comment: @ThePointer *Every* equation is in the context of the text above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `fleqn` option, you can  use the `ceqn` environment from `nccmath`. The`fleqn` environment takes an optional argument to specify the value of `\mathindent` which gives you full control on the position of the equation. B.t.w., needless to use `\dfrac` in displayed equations.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\begin{document}
\raggedright
{\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}

We first convert the second-order nonhomogeneous Cauchy-Euler differential equation into standard form:
\begin{align*}
\frac{ d^2y }{ dx^2 } + \frac{2}{x} \frac{ dy }{ dx } - \frac{4y}{x^2} = 4x
\end{align*}

\begin{ceqn}
\begin{align*}
\frac{ d^2y }{ dx^2 } + \frac{2}{x} \frac{ dy }{ dx } - \frac{4y}{x^2} = 4x
\end{align*}
\end{ceqn}

\begin{fleqn}[2cm]
\begin{align*}
\frac{ d^2y }{ dx^2 } + \frac{2}{x} \frac{ dy }{ dx } - \frac{4y}{x^2} = 4x
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to control how much indentation the equation has, so that it has some significant amount of indentation towards the right, but not fully centred? For instance, In the image you posted, could we indent the equation up to the word "into", rather than fully centred? Or, in other words, align it under the word "into"?

Comment: I've posted a more complete code to show you, with the `fleqn`*environment*.