# Align \vdots at the center of an `aligned` environment

Tags: equations, alignment, aligned

In the following set of equations, I would like to have the vertical dots, `\vdots`, horizontally aligned at the center of the page. I tried a `gathered` environment nested within an `aligned` environment as given in [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326009/how-can-i-center-an-equation-inside-an-align-environment), but the alignment outcome is not as desired (see image and MWE below).

Please note that I'm not looking to have `\vdots` centered within `=` using for example `\vdotswithin{=}`.

Thank you for any solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            t_1 l_1(x_1) + t_2 l_1(x_2) + \dots + t_{q+1} l_1(x_{q+1}) &= 0 \\  
            \begin{gathered}        
                \vdots
            \end{gathered} \\
            t_1 l_q(x_1) + t_2 l_q(x_2) + \dots + t_{q+1} l_q(x_{q+1}) &= 0.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**

The answer of @egreg is good for the particular example that I first posted, but I'm looking for a general solution as I also would like to do the same thing for the following set of equations:

```
\begin{align*}
    a_{11}x_1 + \ldots + a_{1n}x_n &= y_1 \\
    &\vdots \\
    a_{n+1,1}x_1 + \ldots + a_{n+1,n}x_n &= y_{n+1}.
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define `\cvdots` macro which omits the `\halign` preamble and does centering of `\vdots` over two columns.

```
\def\cvdots {\omit\span\omit \hfil$\vdots$\hfil}
```

```
\begin{align*}
    a_{11}x_1 + \ldots + a_{1n}x_n &= y_1 \\
    \cvdots \\
    a_{n+1,1}x_1 + \ldots + a_{n+1,n}x_n &= y_{n+1}.
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Thank you, @wipet, for the simple solution. Would you please explain the meaning of "centering over two columns"? Besides, could you also remove in your solution the extra vertical spacing between lines?

Comment: Vertical spacing should be solved like in the other answer here, i.e using `\\[-6pt]` etc. Centering over two columns: by default the left column of the `align` environment is right aligned, the right column is left aligned. We cancel this alignment rule by `\omit` primitive, emove the boundary between colums by `\span` primitive and put the text (`\vdots`) to the center of both columns using `\hfil text\hfil`.

Answer (score 6):

For the particular case, I'd trick TeX into thinking that 1 has the same width as q in the subscripts, so the alignment is automatic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\1}{\ooalign{%
  \hphantom{$\scriptstyle q$}\cr
  \hidewidth$\scriptstyle 1$\hidewidth\cr
}}
\begin{gathered}
t_1 l_{\1}(x_1) + t_2 l_{\1}(x_2) + \dots + t_{q+1} l_{\1}(x_{q+1}) = 0 \\  
\vdots \\
t_1 l_q(x_1) + t_2 l_q(x_2) + \dots + t_{q+1} l_q(x_{q+1}) = 0\makebox[0pt][l]{.}
\end{gathered}
\]

\end{document}
```

The trailing punctuation is set in a zero width box, to keep the same width.

[image]

If you want tighter typesetting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\1}{\ooalign{%
  \hphantom{$\scriptstyle q$}\cr
  \hidewidth$\scriptstyle 1$\hidewidth\cr
}}
\begin{gathered}
t_1 l_{\1}(x_1) + t_2 l_{\1}(x_2) + \dots + t_{q+1} l_{\1}(x_{q+1}) = 0 \\[-6pt]
\vdots \\[-4pt]
t_1 l_q(x_1) + t_2 l_q(x_2) + \dots + t_{q+1} l_q(x_{q+1}) = 0\makebox[0pt][l]{.}
\end{gathered}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For an “automatic” version, you need to ensure that when measuring the display the `\multispan` doesn't get in the way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\fixed@vdots{%
  \hbox{\smash{$\vcenter{
    \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }$}}\mathstrut
}
\newcommand{\centeredvdots}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else\multispan{#1}\hfill\fixed@vdots\hfill\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
t_1 l_{1}(x_1) + t_2 l_{1}(x_2) + \dots + t_{q+1} l_{1}(x_{q+1}) &= 0 \\
\centeredvdots{2} \\
t_1 l_q(x_1) + t_2 l_q(x_2) + \dots + t_{q+1} l_q(x_{q+1}) &= 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
a&=b & c&=d \\
\centeredvdots{2} & \centeredvdots{2} \\
x&=y & z&=w \\
\centeredvdots{4} \\
uu&=vv & ccc&=ddd
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to consider getting rid of the "extra" space at the top of \vdots`  (That was a "hot topic" yesterday.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you like the second version?

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering if there is any general solution.

Comment: yes.  thank you.